# how do you install an older version of NuGet in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: nuget, nugetgallery

How do you install an older version of NuGet in vs2010?

Not use NuGet to install a older version of something else, but install say NuGet v1.5 instead of NuGet v2.2?

Comment: Is there any specific reason you are looking for an older version?

Comment: I installed the new one and it constantly wants to "fix" my packages, and if allowed the process breaks them

Answer (score 0):

The older versions of NuGet are available to download from [codeplex](http://nuget.codeplex.com/releases) on the releases page.

[NuGet 1.5](http://nuget.codeplex.com/releases/view/65353) for example is available to download from codeplex: [NuGet.Tools-1.5.vsix](http://nuget.codeplex.com/releases/view/65353).